# std::vector constructor behavior

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, msvcrt, libstdc++, std

Take the following code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, 10);
```

This code doesn't compile with libstdc++. It does compile with Visual Studio's C++ library, however. The behavior I would expect is that `v` is filled with 10 vectors of size 10, and this is what I get with Visual Studio.

The constructor invoked with Visual Studio is the one taking two iterators. The constructor itself is defined as:

```
template<class _Iter>
vector(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
    : _Mybase()
{   // construct from [_First, _Last)
    _Construct(_First, _Last, _Iter_cat(_First));
}
```

There are two versions of the template function `_Construct`. Both have the same signature, but one initializes the vector from a range, and the other initializes the vector with N copies of the value type copy constructed from the second parameter. In this case, the template parameters are only valid for the second version of `_Construct`.

The result is that `v` is filled with 10 copies of a vector that was copy constructed from the value 10. The same code path is taken by constructing it like this, as you would have to do for the same effect using libstdc++:

```
std::vector<int> temp(10);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, temp);
```

Which implementation is correct here? Is this a libstdc++ bug or an extension of Visual Studio's C++ library?

**Edit: Just to clarify, I'm not asking if it should be invoking the range constructor. I'm asking which C++ implementation has the correct behavior, regardless of which path it takes to achieve it.**

Comment: `10` is not an iterator, I think VC++ is wrong here and you are getting the right result just by chance.

Comment: I don't think it's chance. The `_Construct` function that is called has the signature `void _Construct(_Iter _Count, _Iter _Val, _Int_iterator_tag)`, so it looks like it's intended. These two `_Construct` functions are only called from the constructor taking two iterators, as well.

Comment: What compile error are you getting?  Also you probably want to add a space between the closing `>` (ie `std::vector<std::vector<int> > v(10, 10);` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, 10);` to avoid confusing the compiler.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to '__cxx1998::vector<vector<int>>::_M_fill_initialize(__cxx1998::vector<vector<int>>::size_type, int&)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, 10);
```

This should not compile, because the vector's single argument constructor is explicit.

C++03:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

C++11:

```
explicit vector(size_type n);
```

This means a number like 10 can't implicitly turn into a vector of size 10.

Comment: Declaring the constructor `explicit` will not prevent `vector` from being constructed via an explicit cast. In this case, the `vector` is constructed with the statement `_Ty _Newval = (_Ty)_Val`; since it's using an explicit cast, it's able to invoke the `size_t` constructor even though `_Val` is an `int`.

Comment: @dauphic: Before you even get to that point, though, you have requested an implicit conversion of the second `10` into the constructor's second argument.  Apparently, the templated range constructor is circumventing that, which means I would definitely classify this as a bug/extension.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. The issue is the circumvention of the explicit keyword. That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The behavior I would expect is that v is filled with 10 vectors of size 10

Which is exactly what happens with GCC/libstdc++ 4.1.2. The `_Construct` that is called is

```
void std::_Construct<std::vector<int>, int>(std::vector<int>*, int const&)
```

(omitting the allocators). I can't tell you what the standard says about this, but my hunch is that's a bug in an older GCC/libstdc++.

Comment: No, `__CLIBCXX__` is defined as 20110929. Maybe it's a bug with new versions or gcc/clang.